# PHP put "Rough frequency" sox stat into variable from exec

Tags: php

In PHP when I run `exec('sox sound.wav -n stat');`

I get an output:

```
Samples read:             82688
Length (seconds):      0.937506
Scaled by:         2147483647.0
Maximum amplitude:     0.595201
Minimum amplitude:    -1.000000
Midline amplitude:    -0.202399
Mean    norm:          0.004229
Mean    amplitude:    -0.000005
RMS     amplitude:     0.029120
Maximum delta:         1.184857
Minimum delta:         0.000000
Mean    delta:         0.002956
RMS     delta:         0.028785
Rough   frequency:         6938
Volume adjustment:        1.000
```

How do I put rough frequency into a variable called `$freq`.

When I try:

```
$output = shell_exec('sox sound.wav -n stat');
```

or

```
exec('sox sound.wav -n stat', $output);
```

I do not get any returned data in $output.

I would like to so when I echo `$freq;` I see 6938.

Comment: Open the man, there you'll see how `exec` works and what it returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @andyvanee for the tip that sox outputs this data on stderr so you must do a shell redirection to get just number value of Rough Frequency:

```
exec('sox sound.wav -n stat 2>&1', $output);
$freq_explode = explode(':', $output[13]);
$freq = $freq_explode[1];
echo $freq; // returns just value of rough frequency
```

**EDIT / UPDATE:** Incase anyone runs into this same issue... I noticed that sometimes with SOX the first value to return in the array can be "sox WARN wav: wave header missing extended part of fmt chunk" if there is some issue with the .wav... this causes the Rough Frequency to be shifted to the 14th value in the array vs the 13th... there are probably more elegant / better ways to solve this (like maybe there is a way to disable warnings in sox, I don't know, but if you do leave a comment and I will fix or searching just for the "Rough frequency") but for my case / quick workaround / solution this is how I solved that problem:

```
if ($output[0] != 'sox WARN wav: wave header missing extended part of fmt chunk'){

  $freq_explode = explode(':', $output[13]);
  $freq = $freq_explode[1];  

}
if ($output[0] == 'sox WARN wav: wave header missing extended part of fmt chunk'){

  $freq_explode = explode(':', $output[14]);
  $freq = $freq_explode[1];  

}
```